# Use of unassigned local variable, how do i initialize the array

Tags: c#

I have a little problem with my code here :

```
using static System.Math;
using static System.Convert;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[,] matrice;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 4; ++j)
                {
                    if (i == j)
                    {
                        matrice[i, j] = ToInt32(Pow((-1), i)) + 1;
                    }
                    else if (i > j)
                    {
                        matrice[i, j] = ToInt32(Pow((-1), i + j));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        matrice[i, j] = j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do i have to initialize the array? I don't know how to do that...

Comment: `int[,] matrice = new int[6,5];`

Comment: See Ron Beyer's answer. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: [Code: Initializing an Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Also note that c# doesn't support changing the starting indicies, you are expecting matrice to contain indicies from [1..N] but indexing in C# starts at 0 and goes to N-1.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - It's not a typo, the user didn't know to initialize the array.  Typos are like if he wrote "matrice[I, k]=j;" instead of "matrice[I, j]=j".

Answer (score 1):

To initialize the array is simple, just create a `new` array:

```
int[,] matrice = new int[6,5];
```

Also from looking at how your `for` loops are set up, you are expecting the indicies to be numbered [1..N] where N is the upper bound. In reality indicies in C# always start at zero, so when you declare an array, indicies are from [0..N-1].

So in the example, I had to add one to each of the upper bounds so your code wouldn't break. The more ideal alternative is to just change your for loop to be 0..N-1, that way you don't have an empty element.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to initialize the array. When you initialize it, you're allocating memory for the array to store your data